# Eloquent select the first of each distinct 'id'?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an employee table with a field `district_id`. I want a query that selects the first employee from each district.

At the moment I'm manually hardcoding it:

```
$tributes = [
Employee::where('district_id', '=' 1)->take(1)->get(),
Employee::where('district_id', '=' 2)->take(1)->get(),
Employee::where('district_id', '=' 3)->take(1)->get(),
...
];
```

Is it possible to do this using only one eloquent call? *Any volunteers?*

Comment: how you determine the `first employee` ?

Comment: The first row in the database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not used to laravel. But something like below may help. `Group by` is needed for one employee and ascending ID will confirm the first employee.

```
Employee::whereIn('district_id', array(1, 2, 3))
            ->orderBy('employee_id', 'asc')
            ->groupBy('employee_id')                
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try using whereIn in the model

```
Employee::whereIn('district_id', array(1, 2, 3))->get()
```

Comment: That will result in a simple SELECT with a district (Join), he wants only the first employee who belongs to a district.